# How to add custom sort like Most View and Best Selling products in API of Product List in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, rest-api, sort

How do we add custom sorts like Most View and Best Selling products in the API of Product List in Magento 2?

I need to add the most views and best-selling products in `/V1/products` to this API using search criteria.

eg: `http://domain.com/index.php/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[page_size]=10&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][field]=most-view&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][direction]=ASC`

any help on this?

Answer (score 2):

For custom sort filter through api, you need to create custom module,

Create **app/code/Custom/Sort/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="custom_sort_plugin" type="Custom\Sort\Plugin\ProductRepository" sortOrder="10" disabled="false" />
    </type>
</config>
```

create the plugin file app/code/Custom/Sort/Plugin/ProductRepository.php

```
<?php 

namespace Custom\Sort\Plugin;
    
    class ProductRepository
    {
        public function afterGetList(
            \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $subject,
            \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductSearchResultsInterface $products
        ) {
            $searchCriteria = $products->getSearchCriteria();
            $sortOrders = $searchCriteria->getSortOrders();
            if ($sortOrders) {
                foreach ($sortOrders as $sortOrder) {
                    $field = $sortOrder->getField();
                    $direction = $sortOrder->getDirection();
    
                    if ($field === 'most_viewed') {
                        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                            ['report_views' => $collection->getTable('report_viewed_product_index')],
                            'e.entity_id = report_views.product_id',
                            ['views_count' => 'SUM(views_num)']
                        )->group('e.entity_id')->order('views_count ' . $direction);
                    } elseif ($field === 'best_selling') {
                        $collection->getSelect()->join(
                            ['sales_order_item' => $collection->getTable('sales_order_item')],
                            'e.entity_id = sales_order_item.product_id',
                            ['qty_ordered' => 'SUM(sales_order_item.qty_ordered)']
                        )->group('e.entity_id')->order('qty_ordered ' . $direction);
                    }
                }
            }
    
            return $products;
        }
    }
```

After this run the command

**bin/magento cache:clean**

**bin/magento indexer:reindex**

You should be now able to sort products in the /V1/products API using the "Most Viewed" and "Best Selling" sort options.

Comment: getting this error Class "Magento\Catalog\Model\Api\SearchCriteria\CollectionProcessor" not found. my magento version is 2.4.4-p1

Comment: can u comment on this

Comment: apologize, you can also use plugin as well, let me update answer

Comment: updated the answer, can you try now

Comment: Thank u . Let me try

Comment: getting this error Undefined variable $collection in /var/www/html/app/code/Custom/Sort/Plugin/ProductRepository.php when caling api

Comment: try to add the product collection in the starting,

$collection = $products->getItems();

Comment: getting this Error: Call to a member function getSelect() on array in /var/www/html/app/code/Custom/Sort/Plugin/ProductRepository.php:21

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149541/discussion-between-mitul-vadalia-and-devidas).

Comment: any help me on this @Mitul Vadalia

Answer (score 0):

try it like this i think reports and analytics requires auth

```
curl -X GET "https://your-magento-site.com/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][field]=views&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][direction]=DESC&searchCriteria[pageSize]=10" -H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

Comment: this API works for the most viewed product ?

Comment: yes this OOTB, you can try it