# ProductRepositoryInterface plugin how to join another table with sort option?

Tags: product, rest-api, magento2.4, after-plugin

I need to add the most-viewed and best-seller sort options into the **rest/v1/products**  API. I created a plugin to add sort condition for following of below link

[How to add custom sort like Most View and Best Selling products in API of Product List in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/370619/how-to-add-custom-sort-like-most-view-and-best-selling-products-in-api-of-produc/370622?noredirect=1#comment508332_370622)

But in **afterGetList** plugin how to join a table to the collection. i inject Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory but

below my code

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="custom_sort_plugin" type="Custom\Sort\Plugin\ProductRepository" sortOrder="10" disabled="false" />
    </type>
```

ProductRepository plugin file

```
<?php 

namespace Custom\Sort\Plugin;
    
    class ProductRepository
    {
        protected $productCollectionFactory;

        public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
        ) {
        $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        }


        public function afterGetList(
            \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $subject,
            \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductSearchResultsInterface $products
        ) {
            $searchCriteria = $products->getSearchCriteria();
            $sortOrders = $searchCriteria->getSortOrders();

            if ($sortOrders) {
                foreach ($sortOrders as $sortOrder) {
                    $field = $sortOrder->getField();
                    $direction = $sortOrder->getDirection();

                    if ($field === 'most_viewed') {
                        $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();

                        $collection->addCategoryIds();

                        $collection->getSelect()->joinInner(
                            ['report_views' => $collection->getTable('report_event')],
                            'e.entity_id = report_views.object_id',
                            ['views_count' => 'COUNT(report_views.event_id)']
                        )->group('e.entity_id')->order('views_count ' . $direction);

                        //$collection->setPageSize(1); // Change the number to your desired limit
                        //$products->setItems($collection->getItems());
                        //$products->setTotalCount($collection->getSize());


                    } elseif ($field === 'best_selling') {
                        $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();

                        $collection->getSelect()->join(
                            ['sales_order_item' => $collection->getTable('sales_order_item')],
                            'e.entity_id = sales_order_item.product_id',
                            ['qty_ordered' => 'SUM(sales_order_item.qty_ordered)']
                        )->group('e.entity_id')->order('qty_ordered ' . $direction);

                        //$products->setItems($collection->getItems());
                        //$products->setTotalCount($collection->getSize());
                    }
                }
            }
    
            return $products;
        }
    }
```

please help me with this what I am wrong? I am getting records but in response all data not coming.

best seller collection query print like this is the reason all data not coming to the response.

> SELECT `e`.*, SUM(sales_order_item.qty_ordered) AS `qty_ordered` FROM
> `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` INNER JOIN `sales_order_item` ON
> e.entity_id = sales_order_item.product_id GROUP BY `e`.`entity_id`
> ORDER BY `qty_ordered` DESC

Comment: please help me on this